# Copy some formulas to specific cells in a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro that will copy some formulas to specific cells in a worksheet.

When I create the macro, the standard formulas work correctly, however, when I attempt to add a If_Then_Else statement, that works fine when I type it in within a cell, I get a syntax error.   If I take the `"`  out before and after FAILED and Pass, the error goes away however the formula does not work.

Compile error:

Syntax error.

Here is the code:

```
Sub FillDown()

Dim strFormulas(1 To 4) As Variant

With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name

    strFormulas(1) = "=DATE(YEAR(D2),MONTH(D2),DAY(D2))"
    strFormulas(2) = "=DATE(YEAR(E2),MONTH(E2),DAY(E2))"
    strFormulas(3) = "=NETWORKDAYS(G2,H2) - (1)"
    strFormulas(4) = "=IF(I2>1,"FAILED","Pass")"

    Range("G2:J2").Formula = strFormulas

    Range("G2:J20").FillDown

End With
End Sub
```

Data:

```
Starts COL D    COL E                 COL F COL G     COL H   COL I  COL J
Trigger Date    Acknowledged Date   Acknowledged By             
3/13/2015 17:37 3/16/2015 11:29 tech    3/13/2015   3/16/2015   2   Failed
3/10/2015 16:15 3/13/2015 16:28 tech    3/10/2015   3/13/2015   2   Failed
3/13/2015 6:32  3/13/2015 9:27  tech2   3/13/2015   3/13/2015   1   Pass
```

Here is the problem I am trying to solve:

I have two dates that have the date and time stamp.  I need to remove the timestamp and determine the number of networkdays between the first date and the second date.

So my idea was to create a column that creates a "just date" version of the datetime I am given.  I do this to both columns then do a networkdays calculation.  I then want to create a Pass/Failed category that I can conditional format using the text. (I am not expecting that response here.  I can do that part)

The text is posing a problem when trying to create it or copy it in VBA.  I can easily use the formulas if I just type them into the cell then highlight and autofill down.

I feel I am just missing something basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your quotes.

change:

```
strFormulas(4) = "=IF(I2>1,"FAILED","Pass")"
```

to:

```
strFormulas(4) = "=IF(I2>1,""FAILED"",""Pass"")"
```

The doubled quotes `""` will get translated to single quotes `"` when it's pasted into the formula.

You can use the automatic color coding in the IDE (or in the StackOverflow editor) as a reminder that you forgot to do that.

Comment: Thank you.  I figured it was something simple..... You nailed it.  Works like a dream.

Comment: It's always obvious to someone else... :)  Glad that helped.